# jenkins utilizing high load average of CPU with 0 current running build

Tags: jenkins, optimization

I am running a Jenkins Server (version 2.232)  at Centos 7 Server (16Gb RAM and 10 CPU cores)

Sometimes, My Jenkins server even when it is idle it is using high load average CPU, the  web page become slow , after few seconds , Jenkins is crashing ,

I Googled about these issues and i test most the solution was to delete old build, etc but nothing happened.

This is the screenshot from `htop` tool :

[image]

i would understand what is the 11 successive Jenkins process  with high CPU Pourcentage and how i can tune up the utilization of CPU

Thanks